# Unable to expand my partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted, ext4

Im on gparted live with 50GB unallocated partition, but my linux partition can't be expanded.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfv3y.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to expand partition 5. The free space is between Partition 3 and 4. So you'd have to move partition 4 to the left, then it should work.

Comment: Should i move it full to the left or just a bit?

Comment: Shouldn't matter if you move it to the left completely or just by the amount you'd like to expand partition 5. Also depends what you'd like to  do with the remaining free space if you don't use it all for expanding partition 5.